# Algorithms for verifying and solving three-coloring

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np

I found the following problem that I am trying to answer:

> Consider the three color problem where V, vertex set of a bipartite graph. can be partitioned into three subsets such that there is
>   no edge between verticies of the same subset. Show that this problem is in NP by describing:
>
> 1. A polynomial time algorithm for verifying a given graph coloring.
>      [Hint:Use graph traversal].
> 2. A nondeterministic polynomial time algorithm for graph coloring.

For 1) I attempted to solve this problem using search algorithm like depth-first search/breadth first search. At each vertex, I would check to see if any of adjacent vertices have different color from the current vertex. If not, then graph is not colored correctly. This is worst case O(|e|), linear time. Is this correct ? How can I answer this question ? And how would I do part 2)?

Comment: "linear time and not polynomial time" -- that doesn't make sense. Linear is polynomial (if both refer to the same quantity).
Hint: for 2), assume you have solved 1).

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, I was not thinking for some reason. So the approach of part 1 is correct ? And how would I use part 1 to solve part 2 ?

Comment: @David Richerby. I don't understand how to correlate your answer with my question. Please explain.